# order by RANDOM() not working after using <@ and NOT IN in WHERE statement

Tags: postgresql

I'm building a Django REST API and having a PostgreSQL query issue where ORDER BY RANDOM() stops working. I have tables `product` and `service` and I want to receive union results in random order. The where statement needs to check if all items in a list exist in the row and if the `product` or `service` has not been assigned as not interested. The query seems to work but the results are not being ordered in random order. Need Assistance.

`Tables Basic Info (Created by Django Models):`

```
TABLE `product` (
  id character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  tags jsonb NOT NULL,
  ...
)

TABLE `product_item` (
  id character varying(11) NOT NULL,
  id_product character varying(10) NOT NULL,  -- Foreign Key
  ...
)

TABLE `product_not_interested` (
  id character varying(12) NOT NULL,
  id_product character varying(10) NOT NULL,  -- Foreign Key
  id_user character varying(50) NOT NULL,     -- Foregin Key
  ...
)

TABLE `service` (
  id character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  tags jsonb NOT NULL,
  ...
)

TABLE `service_item` (
  id character varying(11) NOT NULL,
  id_service character varying(10) NOT NULL,  -- Foreign Key
  ...
)

TABLE `service_not_interested` (
  id character varying(12) NOT NULL,
  id_service character varying(10) NOT NULL,  -- Foreign Key
  id_user character varying(50) NOT NULL,     -- Foregin Key
  ...
)
```

`SQL Query:`

```
(
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    ('product') AS "type", 
    (product.id) AS "id", 
    (product.title) AS "title", 
    (product_item.id) AS "product_item_id", 
    (product_item.type) AS "product_item_type", 
    (product_item.title) AS "product_item_title", 
    RANDOM() 
  FROM 
    "product_item" 
    INNER JOIN "product" ON (
      "product_item"."id_product" = "product"."id"
    ) 
  WHERE 
    (
      "product"."tags" <@ '[ <ITEMS> ]' 
      AND (
        "product_item"."id_product" NOT IN (
          SELECT 
            "n"."id_product" 
          FROM 
            "product_not_interested" AS "n" 
          WHERE 
            "n"."id_user" = '<USER ID>'
        )
      )
    ) 
  ORDER BY RANDOM() ASC LIMIT 10
) UNION (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    ('service') AS "type", 
    (service.id) AS "id", 
    (service.title) AS "title", 
    (service_item.id) AS "service_item_id", 
    (service_item.type) AS "service_item_type", 
    (service_item.title) AS "service_item_title", 
    RANDOM() 
  FROM 
    "service_item" 
    INNER JOIN "service" ON (
      "service_item"."id_service" = "service"."id"
    ) 
  WHERE 
    (
      "service"."tags" <@ '[ <ITEMS> ]' 
      AND (
        "service_item"."id_service" NOT IN (
          SELECT 
            "n"."id_service" 
          FROM 
            "service_not_interested" AS "n" 
          WHERE 
            "n"."id_user" = '<USER ID>'
        )
      )
    ) 
  ORDER BY RANDOM() ASC LIMIT 10
)
```

Comment: Could you add an example to explain/showing why they are not in a random order?

Comment: The union is likely to remove any sub-query ordering. Do the two sub-queries return a random sub-set or is that broken?

Comment: FYI, if you are indeed using Postgres then quoting identifiers like this \`product\` is not going to work as that is a MySQL quoting style. If the back ticks are supposed to be SO formatting then ignore comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UNION is free to reorder the results of its subqueries, and is likely to do so as part of uniquifying them. Add an ORDER BY RANDOM() outside the UNION if you want the results to have a finally random order.